# Vue.js prevent layout jumps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a couple of Vue.js components that cause content to be pushed aside when they are loaded.

To combat this I have created some CSS rules to are specfically target the custom HTML tags for my Vue components like so component:

```
custom-tag {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    // etc.
}
```

This example would be for a CustomTag.vue. This would take effect when Vue.js has not yet swapped out this custom tag for the corresponding Vue.js component. So this would actually make sure that my layout is correct even without javascript.

Although this works ok this is still far from a perfect solution. I feel like it takes too long for Vue.js to take effect even though it is cached and put into a separate vendor file of only 135KB(gzipped).

I struggle to find any real solutions or information about this for Vue.js so I am wondering how others are dealing with this? Is this a problem on my end with the javascript not loading fast enough or something?

Comment: You might be interested in using [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak)

Comment: @Roy v-cloak is used to remove curly brace tags from the document before Vue has loaded. I am talking about having a default in place for the component before it has loaded. This is something entirely different. There is no syntax to cloak to begin with.

Comment: v-cloak *can* be used to remove curly brace tags, but you can use it to differentiate the before-loaded from the after-loaded in any way you like.

Comment: Can you make up a fiddle (using setTimeout, probably) that demonstrates what you're seeing and describe how you would like it to behave differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite strange but maybe it may be possible with very long templates that the engine have to compiler before rendering.

You should consider first preredering of your templates. I guess you are not doing it if you do have custom tags in your html before the render...
Use [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) if you can. If you come from React you can also find [jsx for Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx) useful, or even write render function by hand (though not recommended).

If you want to totally nullify the time of the first rendering though, the only way to go is to do [server-side rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html). So your app will be served with the initial html structure already there.